# Non conservative torque and lagrangian formalism

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, torque, solid-mechanics

I have a system I would like to describe with a Lagrangian formalism. I model friction on my system with a torque ($\tau$). Having non conservative forces and torques, I use equation:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q} = F_q \label{a}\tag{1} $$

Where $F_{q}$ are the generalised forces. Where should I introduce my frictional torque? Is there an equivalent "generalised torque" for non conservatives torques?

Comment: @G.Smith What's up with all the rollbacks?

Comment: @DavidZ The MathJax didn’t render after each of my edits and I couldn’t figure out why. I’ve never had that happen before.

Comment: Ah okay, weird but hopefully it won't happen again.